# Getting incorrect answer - Sum of Multiples 3 & 5

Tags: python

I have looked at other's code, and tried the suggestions but it didn't help. I need to add the multiples of 3 and 5 up to but not including 100 in python.

I've tried searching through StackOverflow already.

```py
def multiples():
  total2 = 0
  for x in range (1,100):
    if (x % 3 == 0) or (x % 5 == 0):
      total2 += x
      return total2

print(multiples())
```

It says 3 as my output, which is obviously wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You immediately stop looping as soon as you get to `3` because `return` is indented too far.

Comment: You can use some debugging tips described [in this blog](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to help you trace the execution of your code to find this problem.

Comment: wow. rookie mistake. I'm sorry. Thank you!

Comment: @KiarraJ. No need to apologize, we've all been there :)

Comment: We've all been there. Be sure to read the link in my comment above and work on those debugging skills. These are critical as you learn how to code.

Comment: okay, I will. Thanks. and thanks for not bashing me for being a noob lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return` statement is inside the loop in the `if` block, so it's going to return on the first matching number, which is 3.

Simply move it out of the loop:

```
def multiples():
  total2 = 0
  for x in range (1,100):
    if (x % 3 == 0) or (x % 5 == 0):
      total2 += x
  return total2

print(multiples())
```